# Linux mint проблема с открытие окна

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Установил чистый минт. Скачал скайп с официального сайта, установил. День работал нормально.
Затем перестало разворачиваться окно на панели задач висит и не разворачивается. Все остальные программы разворачиваются нормально. Заново инсталировать пробовал

Comment: Так он где-то в своих настройках засомневался. Попробуйте от другого пользователя.

Comment: Скайпа или линукса? Если скайпа, то у меня окно не разворачивается я даже войти не могу, хотя когда навожу оно мини окно разворачивает

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте удалить и установить из репозитория

```
sudo apt-get install skypeforlinux
```

Comment: да так уже пробовал